# set select2 option using array of text values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 for multiselect.I having my array text values.
**ex:**

array = ["a","b"];

I need to select these two after my select2 loaded.I achived using single value But how to achieve the same using array of values.I am stucking on this .anyone help me out.

**Question 2:**

```
var values = ["Test", "Prof", "Off"]; // or to take values as array from other document element;
$("#strings").val(values);
$("#strings").trigger('change'); //trigger change for select2 to set values/styles
```

Using the above i cant able to set selected option in my select2.
**Note**: for this i have  used empty multi select

```
            let long_name = 'a';
            let $element = $('#AGENCY')
            let val = $element.find("option:contains('"+long_name+"')").val()
            $element.val(val).trigger('change.select2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the updated code and based on that you can select multiple options:

```
let $element = $('#AGENCY')
var selectedValues = [];
$.each( ["a","b"], function( key, value ) {
    selectedValues.push($element.find("option:contains('"+value+"')").val());
});
$element.val(selectedValues).trigger('change.select2');
```

Comment: I already mentioned above, Need to select the text field not the val.The code which u gave is to select the val. select2 have id, text. select2.val() means id.

Comment: I have updated the answer can you please look into that?

Comment: Hi i tried but it only selected the last value in the array,not all values..I need all values to be selected that i pass in the array

Comment: s..$("#AGENCY").select2({
     placeholder: "Please select an option...",
     multiple: true,
     closeOnSelect: false,
     data: agency_array
    }); 
    let $element = $('#AGENCY');
    $.each( ["default parent account","Agency","Demo ATD","testcaseatd"], function( key, value ) {
      let val = $element.find("option:contains('"+value+"')").val();
      $element.val(val).trigger('change.select2');
    });

Comment: I have updated code one more time so can you please check it updated code into the answer?

Comment: Welcome, anytime i will help.